# Showing that $k[G]$ is a self-injective module

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $G$ a finite group, and $k[G]$ the group ring. I'm trying to show that $k[G]$ is self-injective, meaning that it is injective as a (left) module over itself.

One possible approach is to show that the functors $\operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(\square, k[G])$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_k(\square|_k, k)$ coincide and noticing that the latter is obviously exact. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings), restriction of scalars is left adjoint to the coinduction functor, namely
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(M, \operatorname{Hom}_k(k[G], N)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(M|_{k}, N)$$
for a $k[G]$-module $M$ and $k$-module $N$, and then taking $N = k$ gives exactly what we want. Nevertheless, I feel like I should be able to describe an isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(M, k[G]) \to \operatorname{Hom}_k(M|_k, k)$ explicitly and yet I'm struggling to do so. For example, we can send $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(M, k[G])$ to the element of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(M|_k, k)$ given by $m \mapsto \varphi(m)(1_G)$, but this doesn't feel right (and I haven't been able to come up with an inverse).

Is there an easy way to construct an isomorphism? Or, alternatively, is there a simpler way to see that $k[G]$ is self-injective? If $|G|$ is invertible in $k$ then this follows immediately by Maschke's theorem, so I wonder if there's any way to extend Maschke's theorem here.

Comment: You just need to notice kG is isomorphic to its dual through inversion in G. You don't get "exactly" what you want by setting N=k, but rather need to use this special property of group algebras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Pedro's comment, $k[G]$ is isomorphic to its dual. Composing this isomorphism (or, rather, the induced isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(M, k[G]) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(M, k[G]^*)$) with the adjunction isomorphism
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(M, k[G]^*) \to \operatorname{Hom}_k(M|_{k}, k)$$
yields
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{k[G]}(M, k[G]) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_k(M|_{k}, k)$$
as we wanted.